# Is there any way around to delete specific folders and files from git repository without making a clone of code on your local machine?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-rm

I'm using GitLab to access git repository of my code.

I don't have any clone or any part of code on my local machine. I want to delete few of the folders and files from the git repository without making a clone of that code on my local machine. I don;t want this since the current code base present in git repo contains lots of garbage files, in results in too much delay in making the clone on my local machine. So I want to delete those unnecessary files and folders from the repo itself.

How should I do this? Can I do this from terminal(I'm using Ubuntu linux on my local machine)? If yes how? If no why?

I searched a lot for this but no where I'm getting the help for the issue im facing.

Please somebody help me.

I also looked for option to delete in GitLab UI but didn't get such kind of option.

If you need any explanation please do let me know.

Comment: Can't you shell onto the machine hosting gitlab and delete the directories from there?

Comment: @Flosculus:Sorry I didn't get what are you saying by means of 'shell onto the machine'? Do you mean get login onto that machine?

Comment: Yes, login, either remotely (shelling, slang), or directly.

Comment: @Flosculus : Actually I'm a newbie to this git. Would you please explain me how to login remotely to git? I've ssh and http URL with my credentials.

Comment: You don't login with git, you login via ssh, and use git on that machine.  TBH its easier to clone, delete the directories, commit and push.  I'm guessing you will only have to do it once.

Comment: @Flosculus:Sorry but I didn't understand what you are trying to say. What is TBH? How could I use git on that machine without logging in remotely to git? If you could give step by step description of the operations I need to do as an answer it would be of great help to me.

Comment: @PHPLover it's entirely possible that you won't be able to log into the server that is hosting your git repository.  You can delete files using the GitLab web interface.  If that's not convenient, you would probably need to clone the repository, make your changes, and push them back.